# Remove duplicates from a list of dicts

Tags: python

I have a list of dicts like this:

```
[{'ID': 'a', 'Number': 2}, {'ID': 'b', 'Number': 5} , {'ID': 'a', 'Number': 6}, {'ID': 'a', 'Number': 8}, {'ID': 'c', 'Number': 3}]
```

I want to remove the dicts that have same key and only keep the one with smallest value. The expected result should be:

```
[{'ID': 'a', 'Number': 2}, {'Id': 'b', 'Number': 5}, {'ID': 'c', 'Number': 3}]
```

Comment: Nice task. What did you try to solve it? [mre]?

Comment: Is the `'ID'`/`'Id'` difference intentional?

Comment: Should that be `'ID'` or '`Id'` or are both possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most efficient solution would be to use a temporary lookup dictionary with keys as `ID`s and values as the current dict which has the lowest `Number` corresponding to that `ID`.

```
l = [{'ID': 'a', 'Number': 2},
     {'ID': 'b', 'Number': 5}, # note that I corrected a typo Id --> ID
     {'ID': 'a', 'Number': 6},
     {'ID': 'a', 'Number': 8},
     {'ID': 'c', 'Number': 3}]
lookup_dict = {}
for d in l:
    if d['ID'] not in lookup_dict or d['Number'] < lookup_dict[d['ID']]['Number']:
        lookup_dict[d['ID']] = d

output = list(lookup_dict.values())
```

which gives `output` as:

```
[{'ID': 'a', 'Number': 2}, {'ID': 'b', 'Number': 5}, {'ID': 'c', 'Number': 3}]
```

---

A piece of advice: given your final data structure, I wonder if you may be better off now representing this final data as a dictionary - with the `ID`s as keys since these are now unique. This would allow for more convenient data access.

Comment: Fair play, should have seen that myself. Need to just convert my lookup_dict at the end...

Comment: @Błotosmętek Fixed it up now.

Comment: @Błotosmętek is right, that will give a different result if the value in the first dict is not the smallest.

Comment: @ChenchengLiu Yeah, I've fixed it now to not add to the `output` list as we go, but just convert the running `lookup_dict` at the end.

Comment: @ChenchengLiu Switching the `2` and the `8` gives the correct: `[{'ID': 'a', 'Number': 2}, {'ID': 'b', 'Number': 5}, {'ID': 'c', 'Number': 3}]`.